# Google maps created dynamically on mouseover show correctly only the first time

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, polyline

I create a google map polyline with coorinates from PHP file. On mouseover it displays a div with the map in it. The first time when i enter with the cursor the map shows correctly but in the second time the polyline isnt drawing + the map is smaller in the div.
Code:

```
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function(event) {

        $(".testhover").on('mouseover', function(e) {

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: 'Paten/ajaxtest',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: {routeid: this.value},
                success: function(response) {

                    var mapOptions = {
                        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                    };
                    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
                            mapOptions);

                    // coordinates
                    var coordinates = [];

                    for (i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
                        var point = new google.maps.LatLng(response[i].lat, response[i].lon);
                        coordinates.push(point);
                    }


                    var Route = new google.maps.Polyline({
                        path: coordinates,
                        geodesic: true,
                        strokeColor: '#FF0000',
                        strokeOpacity: 0.7,
                        strokeWeight: 4
                    });

                    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();    // set bounds
                    for (var i = 0; i < coordinates.length; i++) {
                        bounds.extend(coordinates[i]);
                    }
                    bounds.getCenter();
                    map.fitBounds(bounds);
                    Route.setMap(map);

                    $('#map-canvas').show();
                    $('#map-canvas').css({
                        top: (e.pageY) + "px",
                        left: (e.pageX) + "px"
                    });
                }
            })



        })

        $(".testhover").on('mouseout', function() {

            $("#map-canvas").hide();
        })

    });
</script>
```

html

```
    <style type="text/css">

    #map-canvas{
        display: none;
        position: absolute;
        width: 400px;
        height: 400px;
        padding: 10px;
        background-color: grey;
    }

</style>


<div >
    <button  id="447" value="447" class="testhover">Hover 1</button>
    <button  id="449" value="449" class="testhover">Hover 2</button>
</div>

<div id="map-canvas" ></div>
```

What i am doing wrong here ? Thank you !

Comment: Does the ajax response look the same both times?

Comment: Yes , it passes only the coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved. I dont know why but i needed to move

```
                $('#map-canvas').show();
                $('#map-canvas').css({
                    top: (e.pageY) + "px",
                    left: (e.pageX) + "px"
                });
```

at the beggining after "success".